# Comparing two numbers 9<10

Tags: jquery

I have never met this bug before , whenever my jquery script gets to compare the numbers 9 and 10 or 99 and 100 or 999 and 1000 with 9<10 or 99<100 or 999<1000 I get a faulty result , I get false instead of true. 
How do I fix this jquery bug ? 
Thank you.

Jquery:

```
interval = setInterval(function(){
                $.post('help/retrivetable.php', { tableimpulse : sessid } , 
                    function(watchaget) {
                        if (countcom < watchaget)
                        {
                            countcom = watchaget;
                            $.post('help/retrivetable.php', { newtableimpulse : sessid } , 
                                function(getit) {
                                    $("#chat").append("<p id="+countmsg+">"+getit+"</p>");
                                    var scrolldown = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
                                    $('#chat').animate({scrollTop:scrolldown}, 200);
                            }); 
                        }
                }); 
            }, 50);
```

When countcom = 9 and watchaget = 10 it should enter that if , but I treats it like they are equal and won't get in it.

Comment: Show some code so we can help

Comment: Sounds like string comparing. Make sure to use `+a < +b` rather than `a < b`.

Comment: Also, when it's something as simple as this, it's rarely a "jQuery" bug. Look to your own assumptions first--it's easy to determine the type of things being compared, which is usually the only clue you need in a case like this.

Comment: The thing is I searched this bug on google ,and I found many ppl having this problem.

Comment: @CioroianuDenis That's because many people don't know how to debug.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know how to debug , the thing is when the countcom and watchaget were different from 9 and 10 the comparison would go as intended , and when they were 9 and 10 they wouldn't , I code in C++ too but never ever ran into this problem , why would it be valid for countcom = 7 , watchaget = 8 and when countcom = 9 and watchaget = 10 would be invalid .

Comment: Because they're strings, and compared lexigraphically, not numerically. That's why checking assumptions regarding type is *always* an early step in dynamically-typed languages.

Comment: be sure to check that variable return type of a particular function, method, or other object member returns what you are needing to use. Generally, when I am working with DOM properties, numbers are nearly ALWAYS going to return in the form of a string, as is the same case with setting their values in CSS (i.e., border="1" sets the value 1 as a string, and the DOM parses those strings into ints). To work around it, just typecast your expected values into the type you want to work with, such as using .parseInt().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery is Javascript. If it is a bug, it is not a jQuery-Bug but a Javascript-Bug. (Edit: There is a discussion on this sentence. Read the comments)

Try this solution:

The variables are defined as strings:

```
var a = "9";
var b = "10";
```

This comparison will reproduce your result:

```
if (a < b) ...
```

When you compare two **strings** with the operator `<` you get `true` if the first operand will be sorted lexically before the second. You get this result, because in the lexical order a string starting with "1" will be sorted before a string starting with "9", regardless of its length.

Try this instead:

```
if (a-b < 0) ...
```

The term `a-b` forces javascript to process a numeric calculation. Strings will be converted into numbers.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Yes I will , I am waiting 6 minutes to pass :)

Comment: _"it is not a jQuery-Bug but a Javascript-Bug"_ - It's not a JavaScript bug either, it is correct JavaScript behaviour that happens to confuse newcomers...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Read what I did write, not what you want to read: My sentence started with "If it is a bug, ...". I did not say that this assumtion was true.

Comment: OK, but there _is_ a bug, a bug in the OP's code, so in fact the assumption _is_ true. Otherwise the correction you recommend would be unnecessary...

Answer (score 5):

There's a pretty good chance that your code is comparing strings rather than numbers.

Try using the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function thusly:  `Number(countcom) < Number(watchaget)`.

Comment: I'd avoid getting into the habit of converting strings to numbers with `parseInt` because not all numbers are integers. A more generic way is with the unary plus operator, as in `+countcom < +watchaget`, or `Number(countcom) < `Number(watchaget)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting:

```
[7,8,9,10].sort() // => [10, 7, 8, 9]
```

The sort function casts elements to strings by default. To avoid this:

```
[7,8,9,10].sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }) // => [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two string values. Try parse the string value to int using `parseInt(value, 10)`

In your case,

```
    if (parseInt(countcom,10) < parseInt(watchaget,10))
    {
       ....
    }
```

Hope it helps.